How to interpret self-adjoint operators in matrix algebras?
Let $A\in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ be a symmetrical matrix in the $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ equipped with the usual dot product, and $\{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}\subseteq V$. If i assume that $M^*=M^\intercal$ for every matrix $M$, then $A$ is self adjoint, since  $A^*\in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ shows $A^*=A^\intercal=A$, and hence, the identity:
$$\langle A\vec{v},\vec{w}\rangle=\langle\vec{v},A\vec{w}\rangle$$
Should be true...but it isn't, as can be seen by evaluating the identity:
$$A\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=\vec{v}\cdot A\vec{w}$$
In matrix notation, this would read:
$$A\vec{v}[\vec{w}]^\intercal=\vec{v}\left[ A\vec{w}\right]^\intercal$$ and by appliying transposition properties, we finaly get:
$$A\vec{v}[\vec{w}]^\intercal=\vec{v}[\vec{w}]^\intercal A^\intercal$$
But the LHS is a scalar, and the RHS a matrix, so the equality is clearly false, ans hence, my initial assumption, $M^*=M^\intercal$ must be wrong. Untill now, i thought transposed matrices were the analogues of adjoint operators in matrix algebras, but this suggests that they are not. If that is the case, how can i interpret adjoint operators of transformation matrices?

the vectors are row or column in your notation?

They are supposed to be column.

Your notation conflates elements of $V$ with column vectors which will get you in trouble. Anyway, this computation is incorrect; for column vectors the dot product is $v^T w$ and then there's no issue. You get $Av \cdot w = (Av)^T w = v^T A^T w = v^T (Aw) = v \cdot Aw$ as expected.

Oh! I thought the definition $\vec{v}[\vec{w}]^\intercal$ was standard. What a dumb mistake. To be sure, the notation for column vectors is: $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=[\vec{v}]^\intercal\vec{w}$, and for row ones $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=\vec{v}[\vec{w}]^\intercal$, isn't it? Thanks!
